# Jquery icons does not appear in html

Tags: jquery, html, css, icons

I am trying to use icons in query in my html file like below

```
<div class="navbar" >
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li style="width: 140px;"><a 
                        href="" th:href="@{/}"><i 
                        class=" ui-icon ui-icon-home" style="display:inline-block"></i>Home</a></li>
                    <li style="width: 140px;"><a 
                        href="" th:href="@{/}"><i
                        class=" ui-icon ui-icon-search" style="display:inline-block"></i>Search</a></li>
                    <li style="width: 140px;"><a 
                        href="" th:href="@{/}"><i
                        class="ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick" style="display:inline-block"></i>Create</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here are my css files defined in head tag

```
 <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/filters.css"
          th:href="@{/css/filters.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/css/jquery-ui.css"
          th:href="@{/css/jquery-ui.css}" 
          rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/js/jquery.js" th:src="@{/js/jquery.js}"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js" th:src="@{/js/jquery-ui.min.js}"></script>
```

i am not able to see the icons when the html page loads from the server. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Your last script tag misses the closing '>'. See if that helps.

Comment: No that's not the reason

Answer (score 0):

https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png download icon list from jquery ui icon